# Problem with xticks while plotting datetime object on x-axis

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, time-series

I have a data frame which contains two fields. First one named `date` of type `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`.  Second one named `distance` of type float. 
Name of the data frame is `temp_plot`

```
                     date    distance
0 2018-01-28 00:00:00+11:00      46.2
1 2018-01-29 00:00:00+11:00       0.0
2 2018-01-30 00:00:00+11:00       0.0
3 2018-01-31 00:00:00+11:00       0.0
```

I am trying plot distance grouped by each day on a line graph Using the below code.

```
plt.figure(figsize = (18,18))
plt.plot(temp_plot["date"], temp_plot["distance"], marker = 'o')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(),rotation = 45)
plt.gca().set_xticks(temp_plot["date"])
plt.show()
```

I get the plot

[image: plot i got]

But the problem is the data frame has no date as `27-01-2018`. And I am getting that on the x-axis. How to resolve this?

**EDIT(suggested by @Spinor8)**

**This works**

```
temp_plot["date"] = temp_plot['date'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

Comment: Have you tried it by removing the +11:00 from all the times?

Comment: @Spinor8 works like a charm. By the way, was the problem time zone? May be while plotting it was converting timestamp into the base timezone?

Comment: Yeah, I have seen this issue before.